# Mobile technology products using PHP/Javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wanted to know the mobile technology products which are developed using PHP/Javascript/jquery.

Which are latest mobile products are available in market developed using above mentioned langauges.

Are iphone,blackberry,nokia and etc uses these above technologies to develop product and which are those products.

If anyone has any reference for above question please share their ideas.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, that JavaScript works on almost every single operating system out there. But well, I'm not that much of an expert, so I could be wrong.

But to be more precise on answer to your question:
http://jqtouch.com/ - first google result to be honest!

And, a bit "back in time", I was following a conversation over IRC, where people were discussing iPhone application building using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is server side. If it prints a valid XHTML code, there shouldn't be a problem reading XHTML.

Further, I would use / am using jQuery.

For the alpha release, the following devices have been tested and should have a fairly solid jQuery Mobile experience. That being said, there are still a fair amount of bugs and performance improvements to be tackled before the 1.0 release in January.

```
* Apple iOS: iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad (all versions)
* Android: all devices (all versions)
* Blackberry Torch (version 6)
* Palm WebOS Pre, Pixi
* Nokia N900
```

Older versions of Blackberry, Nokia/Symbian, and Windows Mobile may work but we're still seeing JavaScript errors and rendering bugs that need to be tracked down. We don't yet have phones to test Windows Mobile 7, bada, or MeeGo but these will be added as soon as we can get devices.

Since jQuery Mobile is built on the jQuery core, all pages should also work great on most recent versions of desktop browsers too - Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer, Opera, etc.

See more: [Mobile Graded Browser Support](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/)